# Accounting for zero in number to word translator

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I am creating a number-to-word translator and have it working with one exception.

I am having trouble accounting for zeros, for example if the number `4056` is typed in `'four thousand zero hundred fifty six'` is output. Furthermore if `50` is typed in `'fifty zero'` is output.

What I have so far is included below:

```
def convert(number_str):

    d1 = {0: 'zero',1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three', 4: 'four', 5: 'five', \
         6: 'six', 7: 'seven', 8: 'eight', 9: 'nine', 10: 'ten', \
         11: 'eleven', 12: 'twelve', 13: 'thirteen', 14: 'fourteen', \
         15: 'fifteen', 16: 'sixteen', 17: 'seventeen', 18: 'eighteen', 19: 'nineteen'}
    l2 = ['twenty','thirty','fourty','fifty','sixty','seventy','eighty','ninety']

    if (int(number_str) >= 1) and (int(number_str) < 19):
        return(d1[number_str])
    elif (int(number_str) >= 20) and (int(number_str) <99):
        tens, single = divmod(number_str, 10)
        return l2[tens-2] + " " + d1[single]
    elif (int(number_str) >= 100) and (int(number_str) <999):
        hundreds, tens1 = divmod(number_str, 100)
        tens, single = divmod(tens1,10)
        return(d1[hundreds]+' hundred '+l2[tens-2]+" "+d1[single])
    elif (int(number_str) >= 1000) and (int(number_str) <9999):
        thousands, hundreds1 = divmod(number_str,1000)
        hundreds, tens1 = divmod(hundreds1,100)
        tens, single = divmod(tens1,10)
        return(d1[thousands]+' thousand '+d1[hundreds]+' hundred '+l2[tens-2]+" "+d1[single])

def main():

    user_input = input('> ')
    while  user_input != 'quit':
        print(convert(int(user_input)))
        user_input = input('> ')

main()
```

What logic can I add in order to better handle the use of zeros to bolster this program? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not related to your question, but I suggest doing `number = int(number_str)` at the beginning of your function to reduce the repetition of `int(number_str)` all over the place. This also allows, `d1` to be a list instead of a dictionary.

Comment: @AER thank you sir, i've accepted it

Comment: @Code-Apprentice ok will do, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The numbering system that we use in language developed well before the use of the Arabic numbering system that uses zeros effectively as a placeholder.

I'd imagine some logic in which any zero is not commented upon would work. Purely view it as a place holder to make the numbers to the left a higher 10^n value.

```
def convert(number_str):

    d1 = {0: '',1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three', 4: 'four', 5: 'five', \
         6: 'six', 7: 'seven', 8: 'eight', 9: 'nine', 10: 'ten', \
         11: 'eleven', 12: 'twelve', 13: 'thirteen', 14: 'fourteen', \
         15: 'fifteen', 16: 'sixteen', 17: 'seventeen', 18: 'eighteen', 19: 'nineteen'} 
 # Changed zero to an empty string
    l2 = ['twenty','thirty','fourty','fifty','sixty','seventy','eighty','ninety']
    if int(number_str) == 0: # Catches the unique case when zero is mentioned
      return('zero')
    elif (int(number_str) >= 1) and (int(number_str) < 19):
        return(d1[number_str])
    elif (int(number_str) >= 20) and (int(number_str) <=99):
        tens, single = divmod(number_str, 10)
        return l2[tens-2] + " " + d1[single]
    elif (int(number_str) >= 100) and (int(number_str) <=999):
        hundreds, tens1 = divmod(number_str, 100)
        tens, single = divmod(tens1,10)
        return(d1[hundreds]+' hundred '+((l2[tens-2]+" "+d1[single]) if tens > 1 else d1[tens*10+single]))
        # Added a conditional statement above to deal with numbers ending
        # in a number less than 20
    elif (int(number_str) >= 1000) and (int(number_str) <=9999):
        thousands, hundreds = divmod(number_str,1000)
        return(d1[thousands]+' thousand '+ convert(hundreds))
        # Added a recursive call to save code

def main():

    user_input = input('> ')
    while  user_input != 'quit':
        print(convert(int(user_input)))
        user_input = input('> ')

main()
```

Note that it is edited in two places. Firstly to make the zero an empty string, then to catch the condition where it is simply zero.

Comment: In order to catch 99, 999, and 9999 we have to add <= to all the conditional statements.  Right now, because it is just < 99 <999 and <9999 if the user were to type in any of these numbers it would return 'none' as opposed to the english version.

Comment: @M.C. agreed, edited appropriately. I'm guessing it wasn't you who downvoted me though.

Comment: definitely not aha, my reputation isn't even high enough to make a difference anyways.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add special conditions for zero. For example, the problem with 50 can be checked with an if statement:

```
lif (int(number_str) >= 20) and (int(number_str) <99):
    tens, single = divmod(number_str, 10)
    if single == 0:
        return l2[tens-2]
    else:
        return l2[tens-2] + " " + d1[single]
```

You can write a similar if to deal with a 0 in the hundreds place.